# Waited 2 minutes (plus 5249400 nanoseconds delay) for com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@65b91722[status=PENDING]

Tags: android

Some days ago I generated a signed apk and published it on playstore but now, I've been unable to generate a signed Apk and i got this error,I have no idea on how to fix this. Please Help
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpPcl.png

My build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.securesoft.lucid"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 4
    versionName "4"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.4.0'


testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

}

Comment: I am hitting the same issue randomly when running instrumented tests in Firebase Test Lab.

Answer (score 2):

This issue appeared for me after adding some relatively large image assets. I had recently added a number of PNGs that were 10MB+ in my xxxdpi res folder. After removing those, this issue went away

Answer (score 0):

In my case, some of the png file sizes were too large. I have converted all png files into webp formats, and the problem is solved.